# CSS make card the same height running React and Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using the Bootstrap 4 in React. Currently, the card for Item 1 is shorter than Item 2, but I want both the cards to have the same height.

I am expected to have more cards added to the bottom in the future.

[image]

My CSS file:

```
.CountryDetail {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

.cards {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.icon-size {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.shadow-1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.shadow-1:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.vertical-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.show-hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
    transition: 1s all;
}

.cards:hover .show-hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    color: blue;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

My JavaScript file:

```
<div className="CountryDetail">
    <div className="cards shadow-1 container">
        <div className="row vertical-align">
            <div className="col-2 text-center">
                <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-hover icon-size" icon={faPlane} color="#A9A9A9" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-8">
                <h3>Item 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="col-2 text-center">
                <FontAwesomeIcon className="show-hover icon-size" icon={faArrowRight} color="#A9A9A9" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div className="cards shadow-1 container">
        <div className="row vertical-align">
            <div className="col-2 text-center">
                <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-hover icon-size" icon={faHeart} color="#A9A9A9" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-8">
                <h3>Item 2</h3>
                <span>Under Construction...</span>
                <h2>Testing</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="col-2 text-center">
                <FontAwesomeIcon className="show-hover icon-size" icon={faArrowRight} color="#A9A9A9" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add line-height or height in CSS for `cards` class, but it would mess up the height of the contents inside the card.

If I modify my "cards" class like this by adding min-height:

```
.cards {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I would get this:
[image]

Comment: Since those cards will not be on the same "row", you will have to set a height for the cards. I would recommend creating a card with what you think will be the most information that will be present and then setting a `min-height` on all the cards with that value - or, you can use JS to get the tallest card and set the height of all cards to that.

Comment: I tried what you recommended. I still couldn't get the result that I want. I added the update.

Comment: What do you want to happen? What result do you want?

Comment: I want the height to be the same for all cards (rectangle boxes) and the contents inside these boxes to be vertically center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your need of the same height and centered content, update your CSS to:

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If you set the card to be `display flex`, since you have only one direct child (`row`), you can center that vertically.